# Registry taskbar settings for default user

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I got assigned to change the taskbarlayout for a lot of computers that will be rolled out in close future in our company. I figured the best way to do that would be by editing the registry. I have found out, that I can change them for the current User by adding these registry items in this path:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"TaskbarAl"=dword:00000000
"TaskbarMn"=dword:00000000
"TaskbarDa"=dword:00000000
```

created a registry file for this and when you run it, it instantly works for the current User.

Then I've tried to add the same values to the Local Machine, so it would be applied for the default user like it worked with the startlayout.

The path I used was:

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]`

But that doesn't seem to work. And I have no clue how to do it and why it doesn't work. Could someone explain to me the difference between these two paths? I would really appreciate it.

Also is there a good literature you can recommend to learn more about this topic?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The two paths are as you think. However, the use isnt automatically enforced by Windows. Programs have to be written to check both places and act as required.

The Taskbar, as you have discovered is apparently not written to read from `Local Machine`.

I cant find any references. But thats how it is.

I would suggest that you write a program or a script to cycle through all users and update their registries.

Answer (score 0):

This PowerShell script run as Administrator might do better :

```
REG LOAD HKLM\Default C:\Users\Default\NTUSER.DAT
 
# Removes Widgets from the Taskbar
New-itemproperty "HKLM:\Default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" -Name "TaskbarDa" -Value "0" -PropertyType Dword
 
# Removes Chat from the Taskbar
New-itemproperty "HKLM:\Default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" -Name "TaskbarMn" -Value "0" -PropertyType Dword
 
# Default StartMenu alignment 0=Left
New-itemproperty "HKLM:\Default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" -Name "TaskbarAl" -Value "0" -PropertyType Dword
 
REG UNLOAD HKLM\Default
```